# Generator of union sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mathscr A$ and $\mathscr B$ be two subsigma algebras of $\mathscr F$. Why is $\sigma (\mathscr A,\mathscr B)$ generated by $A\cap B, A\in \mathscr A, B\in \mathscr B$? I know that for a fixed $A$, $\mathscr B \cap A$ is a sigma algebra (trace). But why is that a generator?

Comment: I assume $\sigma(\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B})$ represents the $\sigma$-algebra generated by both $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $T=\sigma(\mathscr{A},\mathscr{B})$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$ (I’m calling it $T$ for ease), let $S$ be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all $A\cap B$ with $A\in\mathscr{A}$ and $B\in\mathscr{B}$.

Note that since $A\in T$ and $B\in T$ for all $A\in\mathscr{A}$ and all $B\in\mathscr{B}$, and $T$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, hence closed under intersections, we have $A\cap B\in T$. Thus, $T$ contains all elements in the generating set for $S$, and so we have $S\subseteq T$.

Now note that, if $X$ is the whole underlyings et, $X\in \mathscr{A}$ and $X\in\mathscr{B}$, then $A = A\cap X\in S$ for all $A\in\mathscr{A}$; and similarly, $B=X\cap B\in S$ for all $B\in\mathscr{B}$. Thus, $\mathscr{A}\subseteq S$ and $\mathscr{B}\subseteq S$, and since $T$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $\mathscr{A}$ and $\mathscr{B}$, it follows that $T\subseteq S$.

Thus we have equality $S=T$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathscr F$?

Comment: I suppose you mean $\Omega$. Thanks for the solution!

Comment: @badatmath Look at your original post. Ther is no “$\Omega$”. I assumed your $\mathscr{F}$ was the underlying set. You certainly never named it.

Comment: Oh that's the sigma algebra containing the 2 but sure